# Getting all posts from an XMLRPC request

Tags: xml-rpc

I'm using the [`XMLRPC::Lite`](http://search.cpan.org/~phred/XMLRPC-Lite-0.717/lib/XMLRPC/Lite.pm) module fetch posts from my website like so:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use XMLRPC::Lite;

my $result = XMLRPC::Lite->proxy('http://example.com/xmlrpc.php)
   ->call('wp.getPosts', '', 'admin', 'xxxxx', {post_type => "tribe_events', number => 20});
```

This returns 20 posts. If I don't include the `number` property, it returns 10 results by default. Let's say I want to get all the posts. Is there a way to do it without setting some arbitrarily large number for the `number` property? Are these results paged somehow?

Comment: yes the pagination is the way to go. The usual `-1` for all posts isn't supported as it's filtered through `absint()`. Also note there's a new kid on the block:  [Rest API](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/) ;-)

Answer (score 0):

OK, doesn't look like there is a way to do this. I see now there is an `orderby` and `offset` property which can be used by the client to make repeated calls to get all the posts.